# MongoDB - Update element inside of multiple Arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

i would like to update Elements that are nested inside of multiple Arrays, like:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  items:[{
    item_id: 1,
    desc:[{
      desc_id: 1,
      description: "Test entry"
    },
    {
      desc_id: 2,
      description: "Test entry 2"
    }]
  }]
}
```

How is it possible to edit "description" inside of the first desc element with Node and Mongoose.
I tried:

```
Client.updateOne({"items.desc.desc_id": 1}, {$set:{"items.$.desc.$.description": "Other test entry"}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update only the first `desc` item try:

```
Client.updateOne({
  "items.desc.desc_id": 1
},
{
  $set: {
    "items.$.desc.0.description": "Other test entry"
  }
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example - by index](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7QxTWi1VCdC)

**EDIT:**

You were using the positional `$` operator which update the first match.
If you want to search the inner array by the `desc_id` use the `$[<identifier>]`:

```
db.collection.update(
  {"items.desc.desc_id": 1},
  {$set: {"items.$.desc.$[item].description": "Other test entry"}},
  {arrayFilters: [{"item.desc_id": 1}]}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example by desc_id](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LZGYcwfuE7Z)

But you are still using the positional `$` operator for the external array, meaning you will only update the first match inside it.

To update **all** items **according the desc_id**, use the all positional operator `$[]` for the external array:

```
db.collection.update(
  {"items.desc.desc_id": 1},
  {$set: {"items.$[].desc.$[item].description": "Other test entry"}},
  {arrayFilters: [{"item.desc_id": 1}]}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example all items by desc_id](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kpn4jraL6uX)

Comment: That isnt really what i am looking for. I dont really want to search them by the Array index, i want to search them by the desc_id.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly